# Getting into web scraping with python iterating through html tags

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping

Wrote a Python script to scrape this website https://lumiwallet.com/assets/ for all of its asset listings. I've managed to get the name of the 1st coin "Bitcoin" but no ticker. There are 27 pages on the website with 40 assets per page my intention is I would like to scrape names & tickers for all assets on all 27 pages then turn it to a pandas data frame then to a csv. file with a column for names and a column for tickers. I think the solution would be to write a for loop that iterates through the name tags also looking to get the asset ticker but only getting the name, but because I'm an amateur I not sure where to put the for loop is that's the solution or maybe that's not the solution. I've included an image of my output. [image]

'''

```
from urllib import response
from webbrowser import get
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from csv import writer
from csv import reader
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlencode

API_KEY = '7bbcbb39-029f-4075-97bc-6b57b6e9e68b'

def get_scrapeops_url(url):
    payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'https://proxy.scrapeops.io/v1/?' + urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url

r = requests.get(get_scrapeops_url('https://lumiwallet.com/assets/'))
response = r.text


#list to store scraped data
data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
result = soup.find('div',class_ = 'assets-list__items')



# parse through the website's html
name = soup.find('div',class_ = 'asset-item__name')
ticker = soup.find('div',class__ = 'asset-item__short-name')

#Store data in a dictionary using key value pairs
d = {'name':name.text if name else None,'ticker':ticker.text if ticker else None} 

data.append(d)

#convert to a pandas df
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_df.to_csv("coins_scrape_lumi.csv", index=False)

print(data_df)
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using "proxy_scapes", if you may parsing native url? You gets HTML.

In your code add second '_', for get ticker

```
result = soup.find('div',class__ = 'assets-list__items')
```

For get all tasks, you may using find all and cycle

```
from urllib import response
from webbrowser import get
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from csv import writer
from csv import reader
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import urlencode

API_KEY = '7bbcbb39-029f-4075-97bc-6b57b6e9e68b'

def get_scrapeops_url(url):
    payload = {'api_key': API_KEY, 'url': url}
    proxy_url = 'https://proxy.scrapeops.io/v1/?' + urlencode(payload)
    return proxy_url

print(get_scrapeops_url('https://lumiwallet.com/assets/'))
r = requests.get(get_scrapeops_url('https://lumiwallet.com/assets/'))
response = r.text


#list to store scraped data
data = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(response,'html.parser')
result = soup.find('div',class_ = 'assets-list__items')



# parse through the website's html
name = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'asset-item__name')
ticker = soup.find_all('div',class_ = 'asset-item__short-name')

#Store data in a dictionary using key value pairs
for i in range(len(name)):

  d = {'name':name[i].text if name[i] else None,'ticker':ticker[i].text if ticker[i] else None} 

  data.append(d)
print(data)

#convert to a pandas df
data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

data_df.to_csv("coins_scrape_lumi.csv", index=False)

print(data_df)
```

For getting other pages, you may simulate clicking, bs4 doesn't have this function, and you need selenium, or tkinter. or other libraries.

Comment: Thank you Vlad will try to add clicking simulation now.

Comment: You will not be able to add a click simulation because there are no clickable elements received through your API

Comment: Also i am using "proxy_scapes" because i was getting a 403 error when parsing the native url

Comment: And you will not be able to write the url in such a way as to get the right page, because pagination is performed by the client

Comment: so in this case i could only scrape the 1st page? ):

Comment: I tried to look inspect the webpage's HTML code to see if there was an external URL JSON where the asset data was stored and couldn't find anything

Comment: In this case, you will be able to request only one page, or you will have to look for an api that supports the clickability of elements, or do not use an api and use a proxy in some other way.

Comment: Error 403 means access is denied, check out the service documentation for reasons

Comment: Or can you find some other service that will provide you with ready-made tickers in json format

Comment: @Zer0chance_ You can scrape the whole thing with Selenium handling the page clicks. Perhaps there is a more elegant way to accomplish this task (unknown to me, unfortunately), but I am familiar with how to do it with web automation. I posted a solution that should hopefully work for you if you'd like to read it and try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Because each page of listings on this site is contained within the same URL, we can't get each one by name directly, so I'm opting to use Selenium browser automation to handle the page clicking. This script will take you to the webpage, scrape the first page, then loop through a series of clicking and scraping 26 times. 27 total pages are scraped, and 26 clicks are made to the next page. A list of the text contents are concatenated, then string splitting is utilized to separate the listing names and the tickers, which are separate by a newline character "\n". Finally, those are turned into a pandas dataframe which is exported to CSV, in "write" mode, so it will overwrite previous copies of that file whenever the script is executed.

The only thing you should need to do before it will work as intended, is to make sure you have selenium installed and updated, along with a version of chromedriver that matches your Google Chrome browser version. Then, you will need to replace text in this line, because my chromedriver path won't work for you: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"YOUR CHROMEDRIVER PATH HERE", options=options)` And point the webdriver to the location of chromedriver on your machine.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://lumiwallet.com/assets/'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"YOUR CHROMEDRIVER PATH HERE", options=options)
driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(3)

def get_assets():
    assets = []
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    asset_list = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "assets-list__items")
    page_assets = asset_list.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "asset-item")

    for asset in page_assets:
        assets.append(asset.text)
    
    return assets

def click_next_page():
    next_page = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#__layout > section > div.app-container > div > div > div.assets__body > div.assets-list > div.assets-list__pagination > div > div:nth-child(3) > div.pagination__item.pagination__item--next")
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_page)
    driver.implicitly_wait(3)

assets = get_assets()

for i in range(26):
    click_next_page()
    assets += get_assets()

listings = []
tickers = []

for asset in assets:
    new = asset.split("\n")
    listings.append(new[0])
    tickers.append(new[1])
    
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(listings, tickers)),
                  columns = ['Listing', 'Ticker'])

df.to_csv('lumiwallet_listings.csv', mode='w', index=False)
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this. Cheers!

Comment: Hey, I was able to add my get the Chrome driver version or my Chrome browser and added the path to my code.  I noticed that in your code, you have the letter 'r' before the quote which altered my string and made the texts RED
below is my path.

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/name/Downloads/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver", options=options)

Comment: however I'm getting this error.

Documents % /usr/bin/python3 /Users/name/Documents/lumi_selenium.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/name/Documents/lumi_selenium.py", line 12, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"/Users/name/Downloads/chromedriver-mac-arm64/chromedriver", options=options)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'options

Comment: @Zer0chance_The "r" character before a string means that you want python to interpret it as a raw string. I often do this with file paths because without it the forward or backslashes can cause issues. You can try removing it and see if it works for you. Also your path should explicitly fully name the file including the type, which is a .exe. Mine looks like this: r"C:\Users\howle\Desktop\chromedriver.exe". Make sure you copy the full file path and see if that works.

Comment: @Zer0chance_Hey, do you mind accepting my answer? I took the time to solve your entire problem for you. Basically the only thing I can't do for you is add your specific file path. This is a tested solution and it satisfies everything you asked for in your question.